# How to know list of applications installed in my server?

Tags: configuration, mysql

I got one LINUX server in which Oracle LINUX 5 is installed. I have installed MySQL 5.1.73-community version. Now, I have to configure the variables. When I checked available memory through `cat /proc/meminfo` command, I got below output:

```
MemTotal:      1927692 kB
MemFree:        446620 kB
Buffers:        619140 kB
Cached:         214340 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:         649660 kB
Inactive:       725232 kB
```

Now, it seems that system has only 2GB memory (RAM) in which only 0.4 GB is free. Can I know what are other applications have been installed in this machine?

Comment: How is RAM space related to list of installed applications? I mean you would not have installed applications in RAM. Even with just mysql alone installed, if you have memory inefficient program running, the command you use would give a much more worse memory. The command that you need to use is `df -h` to check the disk space.

Comment: “MemFree” lists memory that is free, i.e. wasted. At the moment about 20% of your memory is wasted. You have about 0.8GB used by programs, the rest is disk buffers/cache. This is a reasonable ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command to list all the applications installed in your system.

```
rpm -qa | less
```

Another way is to use the below command.

```
 yum list installed
```

Oracle has infact documented this in their link [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/virtualsysadminday/Package+management+with+RPM+and+yum).

Answer (score 1):

To check the memory usage of your system you should be using `free`.

To use:

```
$ free -m
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
         Mem:          1504       1491         13          0         91        764
         -/+ buffers/cache:        635        869
         Swap:         2047          6       2041
```

The value under **shared** and **-/+ buffers/cache** is your current available memory.  In this case it's 869 MB.  For more info see [here](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

To see what programs are installed use `rpm`

```
$ rpm -qa
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 'atop -m'
This will show which services are using RAM, and how much. You can restart those in
cd /etc/init.d 
service service_name restart

This may help a bit. Also you can stop services that are not needed in this directory. So if a program is running, and you don't need it then
service i_dont_need stop